# Java n-node tree

Tags: java, xml, algorithm, tree

I'm trying to write Java code for the following figure. Where,

if node:4 will create following separate 4 trees. Number of node in

```
LEVEL1 (yellow) : 1 node
LEVEL2 (green) : n-1 node
LEVEL3 (blue) : n-2 node
```

see image for node:4

[image]

Another way if node : 5 then,

```
LEVEL1 (yellow) : 1 node
LEVEL2 (green) : n-1 node
LEVEL3 (blue) : n-2 node
```

see image for node:5

[image]

And so on. Thanks in advance for kind help.

Comment: Do you mind showing some of your code?

Comment: atleast post the image you are talking about.

Comment: Please be more specific about the desired result. In each tree, for each level there must be one node less than than nodes on the previous level and the permitted node labels are the ones which can be found on the path to the root of the connected component? Are there always exactly 3 leves in total?

Comment: Yes always three levels.

Answer (score 1):

How to solve is what is important here.
Start top-down, and work out the logic.

```
List<Tree> makeTrees(int n) {
    List<Tree> trees = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        Tree tree = makeYellow(n, i);
        trees.add(tree);
    }
    return trees;
}

private Tree makeYellow(int n, int yellow) {
    Tree tree = new Tree();
    Node node = new Node(yellow, Color.YELLOW);
    tree.add(node);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (i != yellow) {
            Node green = makeGreen(n, yellow, i);
            node.add(green);
        }
    }
    return tree;
}
```

And so on.

As you see, at the top for the yellow nodes a simple for suffices. Instead of already working everything out in detail, **anticipate** the further solution, call `makeGreen` and determine what it should return and what info it needs.

Try to find patterns.

Such homework is best done oneself in order to train solving such puzzles, and being mentally rewarded.